# SQL Access query speed

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-performance

I have the following query in my Access 2003 database:

```sql
SELECT 
    Projet.OTP AS OTP, 
    NumeroDA, 
    SUM(Quantite*PrixReelCommande) AS PrixTotal, 
    FIRST(Fournisseur1) AS Fournisseur, 
    FIRST(Projet.NumeroCommandeReservation) AS NumeroCommande, 
    FIRST(Projet.GestionContrat) AS GestionContrat, 
    FIRST(Projet.Acheteur) AS Acheteur, 
    MIN(DateLivraisonContractuelle) AS DateLivraisonContrat, 
    MAX(DateFournisseurLivraison) AS DateLivraisonFournisseur, 
    FIRST(InfoProjet.NomInstallation) AS NomInstallation, 
    FIRST(InfoProjet.TitreMandat) AS TitreMandat
FROM Projet LEFT JOIN InfoProjet ON Projet.OTP=InfoProjet.OTP
WHERE NumeroDA Like "#*" And NumeroDA IN (
                                            SELECT NumeroDA FROM Projet 
                                            WHERE NumeroCommandeReservation="" Or NumeroCommandeReservation Is Null Or NumeroCommandeReservation="0"
                                        )
GROUP BY Projet.OTP, Projet.NumeroDA
ORDER BY Projet.OTP, Projet.NumeroDA
```

The table Projet has ~2500 rows and InfoProjet has only 200 rows. Opening either of this table in Access takes less than 1 second. However, executing the above query takes more than 5 seconds.

I would like to know if there is anything I can do to improve the performance of this query. Is there something in the query that I should avoid performance-wise? Or am I just under Access limitations? I guess that using `Like` in the subquery doesn't help, but there must be something else that slows down the query.

Comment: Do you have index on [OTP] on both table? If so, does index include column NumeroDA. Do you have index on NumeroCommandeReservation, as well as include NumeroDA?

Comment: No index on OTP, there are multiple rows with the same OTPs. But we can set non-unique index in Access, do you think it would help in this case? Same for NumeroDA, there are multiple rows with the same NumeraDA and NumeroCommandeReservation. The PKs are NumeroListe and NumeroArticle, both indexed with duplicate support.

Comment: It doesn't have to be unique, non-unique index can also help query, if you can create composite index or covering index, which can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using any Distincts in the subquery, could you simplify it a little by taking that part out? (I can't test this right now though, so I'm not entirely sure it would give the same results)

```sql
SELECT 
    Projet.OTP AS OTP, 
    NumeroDA, 
    SUM(Quantite*PrixReelCommande) AS PrixTotal, 
    FIRST(Fournisseur1) AS Fournisseur, 
    FIRST(Projet.NumeroCommandeReservation) AS NumeroCommande, 
    FIRST(Projet.GestionContrat) AS GestionContrat, 
    FIRST(Projet.Acheteur) AS Acheteur, 
    MIN(DateLivraisonContractuelle) AS DateLivraisonContrat, 
    MAX(DateFournisseurLivraison) AS DateLivraisonFournisseur, 
    FIRST(InfoProjet.NomInstallation) AS NomInstallation, 
    FIRST(InfoProjet.TitreMandat) AS TitreMandat
FROM Projet LEFT JOIN InfoProjet ON Projet.OTP=InfoProjet.OTP
WHERE NumeroDA Like "#*" And (
     NumeroCommandeReservation="" Or 
     NumeroCommandeReservation Is Null Or 
     NumeroCommandeReservation="0")

GROUP BY Projet.OTP, Projet.NumeroDA
ORDER BY Projet.OTP, Projet.NumeroDA
```

Comment: It does work and gives me the same result in less than a second. So the problem is the subquery with the `IN()` function. Seems like Access doesn't like it. I will accept your answer as it does solve my problem, I will be more careful with this now. This query probably still coulb be improved.

Comment: In the interest of improving the query, those `First()` statements make me a little nervous. They could be hiding something important.  I recommend getting rid of those `First()` statements and instead putting those fields in the Group By statement. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this and see how many rows it returns:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Projet LEFT JOIN InfoProjet ON Projet.OTP=InfoProjet.OTP
WHERE NumeroDA Like "#*" And NumeroDA IN (
                                        SELECT NumeroDA FROM Projet 
                                        WHERE NumeroCommandeReservation="" 
                                        Or NumeroCommandeReservation Is Null 
                                        Or NumeroCommandeReservation="0"
                                    )
```

Reason: Join may be returning more rows that you'd expect, but as you have only `MAX/MIN/FIRST` Aggregates you may not notice.

Comment: The original query only returns 23 rows, which is okay. I just tried your query, which is as long as my original query, and it returns a count of 111.

Comment: @dnLL in this case I think the only things that will help are adding indexes as ljh suggested or re-writing the query to remove the sub-query and move it to a join or the where section.

Comment: PowerUser's solution actually fixed my problem, but I will look into adding indexes also.